# Blender crashes during normals bake

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking

my blender crashes with out any warning message while baking high poly on low poly normals map in cycles.

Any way to make it work?

[image]

[image]

My hardware:

1. CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8600K CPU @ 4.3 GHz 6 cores
2. Ram: 8.0 GB
3. GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 Vram- 4.0 GB
4. OS: Win 10 64 bit.

Comment: Your ray distance is too low. You have it set to zero. bump it up a little. You can go really small, but zero is too far. You might recall a part of Blender Guru's normal bake tutorial on Youtube where he had a hole in the anvil that was getting weird artifacts. He had to shrink the ray distance, if I recall. But the distance must have length. Let me know if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it crashing? or just taking a long time I've had bakes last up to ten minutes it'll say Blender is not responding at the top of the window but eventually the bake will finish. I would recommend using a cage for normal map bakes.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with you hardware, maybe just close other programs while baking and maybe lower the poly count of your mesh and then just use a subdivision modifier so it's less laggy. Also the more windows you have open just cause more lag so just keep it to the baking window and close the 3d view and node view windows.